# Is there a problem using Check and Quiet with LinearModelFit?

Tags: warning-messages, estimation

I am using `LinearModelFit` in conjunction with `Quiet` and `Check` because I need to control when messages are generated. I think messages leak out from `Check`.

I am using the following code:

```
ClearAll[quietCheck]
SetAttributes[quietCheck, HoldFirst]
quietCheck[x_] := Module[{res, msg = {}},
  res = Quiet[Check[x, msg = $MessageList; $Failed]];
  <|"result" -> res, "messages" -> msg|>
 ]
```

Let's check that the trap works:

evaluating

```
quietCheck[Message[f::argx, 1, 2]]
```

returns

> ```
> <|result->$Failed,messages->{f::argx}|>
> ```

and evaluating

```
quietCheck[4 + 35 - 1]
```

returns

> ```
> <|result->38,messages->{}|>
> ```

as expected.

Now I will test it on a more realistic scenario. This is the data I'm currently using:

```
 data = Uncompress[
   "1:eJx91X9IE2EYB/BjDRERE5GwElOJMqTCQERieBrDRE00EFkRY8jYRZp4a95WCCEhw2z5YyhYgeYsZUmEjRERK8zMimpJIVEhohESkpouW9Bzb/9E7/e6Pwbjw3Pvj+fHZVhOV1krBEGQ9fRTJsl2q+7vf411n38Of4s4RGlqkyD8YwW5J+6VDDRBy7jdaOvow3ZzojTP7SOb5k2X3bplJkURpY+8vVw/Oue7S3EB3tayjnseGbCxfSZhk20dX8+tO6Dlj006HiyR+Xk7Ykmsye8kG+Dt2tKNidJbOG45XG5JDOK4w7Ou5FEfNpaHcbzP3vqkllAQ29nk0eLZKLY3tJWaY01wPXa+S03wDIGVX9OKhI2dXcPcheb5V1ZseSrGk13mzRD37nrDVmwsbpnO18vbyfv2rhQzmZs39TrDxWSdGjU4gvNH1VKQO4TXYzaI83fwU0V7jwvHVSfsvXN1Hq/3ZVdOrH8bvjO1rOPD/8lRHa55lge7AvfSEprqN646Rekib6ZaOsVTMhdvrzPf/2hewPY4nYbBHrIejRy9VeAs6ErRVyfMYGM5silwvkQpteUiWYi3MrVgDDiOblOXfQbHxfpTTbUyjmM93Y3nGXXR2OQC2Spvgvr4yRZ5e9ZvDKxspvXWeHtC47MwkyyiURMmbOx8HvxO6jBDXA5ZVCNHaWQxes5o6n7PGiLb4ONiznsPtSl4ll9YrAymteK7ZvdpVmAfsXkmOGHttp2irtaYE2r71e/DcayWNIz1X5ET9lgRtVGm0Ql7bDeFpYpk3bxtNNONVpK18/aQ2i/glUWpgbc5X994+qAMe4zNXS82ltthMg9vI9Qqlisy7Hc2CxSyNt52qAmskuH83L7/w86YUvzOCH3C+w6QeTW+tyX4DC+e0xMn/8nRb744YpA="
  ];
```

Evaluating on purpose

```
f = quietCheck[LinearModelFit[Take[data, 5], Table[x^i, {i, 1, 4}], {x}]]
```

returns

> ```
> <|result->FittedModel[-2.05346*10^10+<<6>>],messages->{}|>
> ```

Notice how there appear to be no messages generated. Next, evaluating

```
quietCheck[f["result"]["RSquared"]]
```

returns

> ```
> <|result->$Failed,messages->{Power::infy}|>
> ```

notice that now there's a message generated, when trying to access the `"RSquared"` 'property' of the previous output.

This can only mean one of two things, either:

1. `FittedModel`-the output of `LinearModelFit`-does not store the R squared value, but it re-calculates it on the fly every time the relevant property is requested; this sounds counter-intuitive but it's possible, or
2. there's a leak of messages somewhere.

Does anybody have any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you see is independent of `quietCheck`:

```
In[17]:= LinearModelFit[Take[data, 5], {x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, {x}];

In[18]:= %["RSquared"]

During evaluation of In[18]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

Out[18]= 1.
```

meaning your conclusion

> FittedModel does not store the R squared value, but it re-calculates it on the fly

must be true.